# How to sum this series and what is the sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the series $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ \log [ (1 + 1/n)^n (n+1)] }{ (\log n^n) [ \log (n+1)^{n+1} ] }, $$ which we can express as $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ \log (n+1)^{n+1} - \log n^n }{ (\log n^n) [ \log (n+1)^{n+1} ] } = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} [ \frac{ 1}{\log n^n} - \frac{1}{\log (n+1)^{n+1}} ], $$ which is a telescoping series whose sum is $1/\log4$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

This is correct and very nice, with one caveat.  To justify a telescoping series converging, you need to show the final term (i.e. the term in the partial sum) goes to zero.  So in this case you need to show that
$$
\frac{1}{\log (k^k)}
$$
goes to zero.  This should be easy, but in some cases you have to be careful.

EDIT: In general the telescoping series converges as long as this final term goes to *anything*, i.e. as long as the final term converges.  But if it converges to something other than zero, then you have to factor that into your calculation of the sum.  For instance, if we found that $\frac{1}{\log(k^k)}$ converged to $.03$, then we would calculate our final answer to be $\frac14 - .03$.

Comment: You're right, but in general what we require is convergence (not necessarily to zero) of the sequence whose terms are involved in the telescoping. That is, if we have a series $\sum a_n$ such that $a_n = b_n - b_{n+1}$ for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, then $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if the sequence $\{b_n\}$ does.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud of course you are correct!  Let me edit.

Answer (score 2):

Nice argument! Looks correct to me.